# Why doesn't useTransparentBounds() search outside Matcher's region?

Tags: java, regex

I tried to use [`useTransparentBounds()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#useTransparentBounds%28boolean%29), but it doesn't seem to work as expected (as seen in [ideone](http://ideone.com/a9T5zL)). In the following snippet, I expected `m.find()` to find a match because transparent bounds were enabled, thus allowing for the `Matcher` to search outside of its region boundaries. Why doesn't this work?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // match everything preceded by X
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*(?<=X)").matcher("Foo BarX Baz");

        // limit matcher to first chars outside of normal lookahead scope
        m.region(0, 4);

        // matcher should still find a match because of transparent bounds
        m.useTransparentBounds(true);

        // this fails to find a match! why?
        System.out.println("found=" + m.find());
        System.out.println("result=" + m.group());
    }
}
```

(I'm using J2SE 6 (1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909) on Mac OSX Mountain Lion)

Comment: what are trying to match..your regex seems to do nothing useful..and y you are limiting it upto `0-4`..this is not range of match since it matches `Foo BarX` which is in the range of 0-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `(?<=X)` is a lookbehind, not a lookahead; I think you meant `.*(?=X)`.  Now let's start by examining what what happens when you don't limit the matching region.

Initially, `.*` consumes the whole string (`"Foo BarX Baz"`), then hands control to `(?=X)` (the lookahead), which asserts that the next character is `X`.  That fails (obviously), so the matcher gives back the last character and tries consuming just `"Foo BarX Ba"`, but he lookahead fails again.  It continues like that until it reaches the point where it's consuming `"Foo Bar"`.  The next character is now `X`, so the lookahead succeeds.

If you limit the region to `(0,7)` you might expect it to continue working.  *You* know the next character is `X`, and anyway, you're only trying to *look* at the `X`, not consume it.  But no, the matcher can't even see it.  It behaves exactly as it would if you had applied it to `"Foo Bar"` to begin with.  It doesn't bother looking at the character after the `r`, because it believes there **are** no characters after that.

That's the default behavior, anyway.  What `useTransparentBounds(true)` does is enable the matcher to look beyond the region's bounds for the purpose of matching zero-width assertions (lookarounds, word boundaries, etc.).  You still can't *consume* anything that's not in the current region; that's not what it's for.

The reason your regex doesn't work is because it's only looking at the first four characters of the string.  For the lookahead to succeed, there would have to be a `X` at index #4 (e.g. `"Foo X"`).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you specified region as `0-4` which is not the region of the match..

i.e. it should be `m.region(0,7);`

It should be `0-7`..This would match `Foo BarX` which is in the range of 0-7 **NOT** 0-4

But what are you trying to match!Your regex doesnt make sense

Comment: `0-4` is meant to limit the matcher's search region. I'm trying to see if `useTransparentBounds()` does what it's supposed to do. As I understand it, the point of `useTransparentBounds(true)` is to allow the matcher to search outside the bounds. Since the target string ("Foo Bar") is outside the `0-4` bounds, using `useTransparentBounds()` should allow the `Matcher` to find the string.